# How can I create a password protected .zip file in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, password-protection, winzip

Winzip claims that it can create a password protected zip on Windows 10, but the Winzip installer fails part way during the installation on Win10.

https://www.winzip.com/win/en/downwz.html

Is there an alternative to Winzip?

Comment: Are you using the current version of WinZip (V24)?  It installs and works just fine on Windows 10. I have it running here.  7-Zip also can create password protected ZIP files and it works on Windows 10 as well. I like WinZip best.

Answer (score 14):

You can easily create password protected archives with **[7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/)**.

[image: creating password protected archive with 7zip]

Create a password for the document, re-enter it, then change the encryption method to AES-256, then press "OK."

Comment: Does not seem to work.  After clicking OK in the above-shown 7-zip dialog box, and then double-clicking the resulting ZIP file in Windows Explorer, the contents of the ZIP are displayed without prompting for the password.

Answer (score 3):

Consider [Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com/), a Shareware file manager for Windows. One, out of a zillion of its features, is handling ZIP files, which also includes an option to enter an *encryption key*, which is used to protect a ZIP file with a password (which has to be entered whenever such file is to be unzipped.

Comment: the Open Source clone [Double Commander](https://doublecmd.sourceforge.io/) can handle it as well. Pack marked files with `Alt+F5` and then check `Encrypt`. It will then ask you for the password.